# Entity Framework query with sub select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have a scenario where I have 3 tables:

- News [Id, Name]
- Users [Id, Name]
- Likes [Id, News, User]

I am trying to write a query that will return all news as well as a column that returns true or false (if the a specific user has or not liked a content).

On SQL I would to something like this:

```
select *, 
(select top 1 id from newslike nl where nl.newsid = n.id and nl.userid = 1) 
from News n
```

How can I achieve that with an EF query?

I already add to my class a NotMapped property for this boolean value

---

Edit:

```
public partial class News
{
    public int Id { get; set; }       

    public virtual ICollection<NewsLike> NewsLike { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool LikedByCurrentUser { get; set; }
}


public partial class NewsLike
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual News News { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can u show your domain classes?

Answer (score 0):

```
News.Where(n => n.Likes.Any(l => l.UserId == userId));
```

Here `userId` is the ID of a desired user. You'll get all news that the user liked.

Comment: Since I have a not mapped property to store the bool value if the user has liked the content, can my query returns a list of news instead of the anonymous type?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's a navigation property from `News` to `Likes:

```
db.News.Select(
    n => new {n.Id, n.Name, UserLikes = n.Likes.Any(l => l.userid == 1))}
    );
```

> Since I have a not mapped property to store the bool value if the user has liked the content, can my query returns a list of news instead of the anonymous type?

Sure, just create a new `News` item instead of an anonymous type:

```
db.News.Select(
    n => new News {
        Id = n.Id,
        Name = n.Name, 
        LikedByCurrentUser = n.NewsLike.Any(l => l.userid == currentUser))}
    );
```

Comment: Since I have a not mapped property to store the bool value if the user has liked the content, can my query returns a list of news instead of the anonymous type?